# Weirdness in XElement.Value and null value

Tags: linq-to-xml

Here is a strange behavior in LINQ to XML. Here is a reference XML document.

```
<Root>
  <First>first</First>
  <Second></Second>
  <Third />
</Root>
```

As you would expect `root.Element("First").Value == "first"` is true.

As you would expect `root.Element("Second").Value == ""` is true.

I would then expect `root.Element("Third").Value` to be `null`. But here is the thing: `root.Element("Third ").Value` return an empty string.

Here is the source code from the .NET framework:

```
public string Value
{
  get
  {
    if (this.content == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string text = this.content as string;
    if (text != null)
    {
        return text;
    }
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    this.AppendText(stringBuilder);
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
  }
```

Is my expectation plain wrong? Is is this a wrong design decision? I would have wrote a `return null` instead of a `return string.Empty`.

Note that there is a `IsEmpty` property telling whether the tag is opened or self-closed.

Comment: I'd think the precise reason as to why this was done depends on the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags), which says `<termdef/>` is an empty element tag, which has the same meaning as `<termdef></termdef>` when the element has no content. I would only return null if no such element exists, much like `el.Attribute("attr")` does. I wouldn't really consider it their design choice, they're just adhering to the spec (which I guess is a design choice in itself, but meh).

Comment: @sbat You should have posted an anwser.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, that's just a design choice, but I would say it's a good one! Consider following query:

```
var items = from e in doc.Elements("name")
            where e.Value.Length < 10
            select e;
```

If `XElement.Value` did return `null` for empty elements, the query would throw `NullReferenceException`! With `String.Empty` it won't do that.

The same thing applies to `Explicit(XElement to String)` conversion. If returns `null` when source `XElement` is `null`, but `String.Empty` when it is empty. It would be confusing if it did return `null` for both.

If you'd like to check if element does not exist **or** has no value, use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method instead of `== null` comparison.

Comment: You can easily avoid a NullRefEx in your query by doing a simple null check so I don't see this example as a good point. There is no apparent good reason to break the rule of "if it does not exist, then return null".